# Excel Auto-Fill a Series Without Mouse (Keyboard Only)

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

When I want to extend a series or something along those lines, I can highlight a group of cells, then click on the bottom right corner of the highlighting box and drag down.  Excel will then attempt to automatically extend the contents as well as it can.  Is there a keyboard function that will allow me to do this?  I like to use the keyboard to avoid repetitive mouse motions.

I can use the shift key and arrow keys to make a selection, but I don't know what (if any) key can trigger this function.

I also don't really know what this function is actually called.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use keyboard short cuts to get to anything that's on the Ribbon. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then you can see the keystrokes next to each section. To bring up the Fill Series dialog box press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Nice, this works well.  The AutoFill option (Alt-F) seems to work well for most of my past use cases.  Using Trend and Growth also allows me to do multiplicative series.  Very cool!  Sort of a lot of keys to press, but I guess that's what I asked for.

Comment: Mnemonics help ... Home FIll Series (Enter).  Thanks for this!

Comment: If anyone finds a *shorter* (non-macro way) / "the official shortcut" to do this **for linear series** please let us know!

Comment: Alt+E+I+S is the older (and faster) way

Answer (score 64):

You're looking for "Fill-Down" or "Fill-Right".

**Select the range** by moving to the cell to start with... then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to where you want to fill the contents to... and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (to fill-down) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (to fill-right).

Unfortunately, there is no shortcut key for fill-left or fill-up.

Comment: This is pretty helpful.  The only thing is that it automatically bases its fill on the first cell only.  This will duplicate a cell, but will not extend a series.  Still, this is very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Actually, it does extend a series.  It will copy any formulas, and modify columns/rows as excel regularly does.  If you wanted to copy/paste values... then just use the copy/paste option (select values -> control+c -> go to destination -> control+v)

Comment: I mean that it won't automatically deduce a series.  For example, type 1 in A1, 2 in A2, and then highlight both.  If you do the Fill-Down with the mouse, it will start counting up automatically.  Since the Ctrl+D method has no way to select more than one source cell, it will only copy more ones.  AFAIK, only additive series will work.

Comment: Interesting... I've never tried that before.  I suppose you could take another route, and put 1 in A1 and =A1+1 in A2 and then fill down & get nearly the same results... but you're right... there should be a way.  You could also assign your own custom short-cut key to the "fill series" option... and then it would give you a menu on how you want to fill the remaining cells...

Comment: This saves me a lot of time!

Comment: "Unfortunately, there is no shortcut key for fill-left or fill-up." Maybe not exactly the same in that it doesn't deduce a pattern, but these shortcuts copy the first cell (hence can't deduce the pattern) in the direction you're extending, to all the other selected cells, including formulae, formatting, etc. Alt-E-I-D for down, Alt-E-I-U for up, Alt-E-I-L for left, Alt-E-I-R for right. Still works with Excel 2016, and I guess the newer versions. Oh wait, my Dad's Office 365 as well.

Answer (score 11):

1. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>↓</kbd>  to highlight where you want the series to go - must include the filled in cell that you want to key off of.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

(Inspired by the answers above and some trial and error)

Comment: This is answer in 4-steps. I would however replace #3 with `ALT+f` because it's an easier layout than reaching for tab.

Answer (score 5):

You can also accomplish this with a macro.

1. Go to View tab -> Macro -> "Record Macro"
2. Choose an optional name, for example Myautofill (no space in name!)
3. Choose an optional shortcut, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
4. Click OK to start recording the macro
5. Go to Home tab -> Editing -> Fill -> Series
6. For "Series in" choose "Columns", check the "Trend" option, then click **OK**
7. Go to View tab -> Macro -> "Stop Recording"
8. Your macro is ready! Select a range of cells and hit the shortcut you chose in step 3.

Comment: I forgot some thing, you should also choose trend in step 7.

Comment: This seems like macro addiction to me. You shouldn't need to use a macro for this, it is a simple task which is central to Excel interaction.

Answer (score 5):

For Excel 2016 (and I presume 2013), I added it to the Quick Access Toolbar (I got rid of the Save button because CTRL-S does that), and I replaced it with Fill Series.

- Go to the Home ribbon
- In the Editing group, click on 'Fill'
- Right-click on 'Series'
- Select 'Add to Quick Access Toolbar'

Now it should appear in the top left of the window. When you press ALT, a number should appear next to the new icon you've added. You can then customise the Quick Access Toolbar and put the 'Fill' option where you want.

I got rid of 'Save' and put 'Fill' there instead, so I can now enter the first two values (e.g. '1' in cell A1 and '2' in cell A2), then select those two and more cells below, and hit ALT, 1, and Enter. The selected cells should then be filled with the series. The mouse is no longer required for this task.

Answer (score 3):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the starting cell
2. Select the target range (using <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, arrows, etc)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste

The target range will be filled appropriately.

---

As [answered by TheCompWiz](https://superuser.com/questions/270018/excel-auto-fill-without-mouse-keyboard-only/270028#270028), using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> would be another method. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C/V</kbd> would let you to fill to any direction and anywhere; while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D/R</kbd> requires less keystrokes.

Comment: Doesn't deduce a series.

Answer (score 1):

But would also have to change 'type' to autofill.. so use

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> and then <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: "down" is not a keyboard key!

Answer (score 1):

Select cell, you want to fill down.

Select the range by <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>arrows</kbd> where you want to fill the contents to.

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit first selected cell.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to fill area.

Comment: I don't find this a working solution, at least in Excel 2007. It doesn't produce a series, only fills down the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut to Fill-down (or fill-Right): 
First select Select what to fill down(or right) then

*Option 1:* To fill-down all the cells(till end of excel sheet): ( **Shift** + ( **End** Then **↓** ) ) Then ( **Ctrl** + **D** )
To fill-Right: ( **Shift** + ( **End** Then **→** ) ) Then ( **Ctrl** + **D** )

Option 2: To fill-down: ( **Shift** + ( **PgDown^*N*** Then **↓** ) ) Then ( **Ctrl** + **D** )
**N**= number of times you need to go down based on your need. You can also go down/up with aero keys or **PgUp** key if you need.

Comment: As mentioned in other answers I believe you have to use Ctrl+R when filling to the right, at least that's how it seems to work in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Fill the first column with 1 and then select the range in which you want to fill the series and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>... series will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type 1 in upper cell.
2. Type =1+(address of upper cell) then press enter.
3. Copy that cell and drag to last sell of required data .
4. Select that row and use *paste special* (Alt+E+S+V) to remove formula.

Answer (score 0):

Assign 'Fill Series' to a position on the quick access toolbar. Let's say position 2 for this example.

Highlight the cell you want to fill down and the empty cells you want to fill - can be done using Shift+Arrow.

Now Alt+2(assigned QA position) then Enter.

Note - Highlight 2 cells plus the targets if you want Excel to infer the numeric series to fill.

Hope this helps and is a bit easier to execute than the Alt+x+y+z+a+b+c then Shift+d+e+f answers above.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use Autofill, use this:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd> and finally  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question,(an answer has been accepted) it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why your solution works with detail and an easy to follow instructions. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and re-edit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need to generate serial numbers in column A.

- Type **1** in the first cell i.e **A1**.
- Press `Down` key to move towards **A2** .
- Press `=` key , select cell **A1** , add **1** to it likewise `=A1+1`and hit the `Enter` key.This will generate the number **2**
- Now hold down the `shift` key and keep pressing `down` key till the last cell where you want to end your series.
- Press `ctrl+d` to autodrag.

Finally you got your automated series of numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Select cell, you want to fill down.

Select the range by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit first selected cell.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to fill area.

Comment: It seems to me that this fills ***a value***.  The question asks how to auto-fill a series; e.g., enter `10`, `13` and `16`, and get `19`, `22`, `25`, ….

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot by default use any hotkey. But you can record for yourself macros. I did it keys *Ctrl+Shift+D*.

First select cells, you want to fill(with filled consecutive cells). Go **View => Down arrow Macros => Record Macros..** On opened window you can fill any name, and any hotkey. After click ok. Select **Home => Fill => Series => select AutoFill radio button then OK** then go again to Macros from view menu and stop recording. Next time you can fill it by your hotkey. Good Luck!

---

When you start recording macros, it records all actions you do (to visual basic codes). So select cells before start recording. And don't forget stop it :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for filling any series. As series don't contain formula, all above listed answers aren't helpful.(You can't write formula when you have series of Step 1, Step 2 and so on)
Go to Fill --> Series --> Select Rows or Columns in **Series in:** and Autofill in  **Type** --> Press OK.

That's it !

Answer (score 0):

1. Type 1 in first cell
2. type =1 + address of first cell
3. now select the cells you want to fill
4. press ctr + D
5. now paste special using Ctr +alt + v 'values only'

congrats you have done.

Answer (score 0):

The faster way to do this is to use the old keyboard shortcut keys which aren't slowed down by the redrawing of the ribbon menu:

**<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>**

If you already have the beginning of the series filled in (e.g., 1, 2, 3) then all you have to do is press enter.

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: only tested in Excel 2013

Select the top cell that you want to fill from.

Select the column range by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to autofill.

Answer (score 0):

Add Excel short-cut yourself.  Open Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts.
Add the shortcut in the red rect below.
[image]