# How do you click and drag lower right corner of a cell (autofill) in excel using the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

If I press <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> I move to the cell before the empty cell.

If I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> I end up selecting everything between the active cell and the next empty cell.

Now if I want to auto fill the same range of cells, what is the keyboard shortcut for that? (Autofill; also known as clicking the handle in the lower right hand corner of the cell and dragging)

Comment: Because it's to short to be an answer `ctrl+d` Note: you will have to highlight the cells first

Comment: Note: The answer is already posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14391773/2097368)

Comment: @50-3 No that isn't it.  I just tired it, and when you select and press CTRL+D, it fills in the value of the top cell.  That's not what I'm referring to.  I'm referring to when you have a sequence for instance ... user01, user02, user03 etc...and you select those cells and then drag to the bottom of the sheet, and each cell increments.  I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut for that.

Comment: Oh you double click it and that fills the rest in. :-p  Still not a keyboard shortcut though.

Comment: Alt>H>F>I>S and then shift+tab>down>down>down and then enter

Comment: Note: The answer is already posted [here](http://superuser.com/a/653947/85584)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a two different function that can be performed using this part of the GUI

## 1st

Fill using formula

**Starting point:**

[image: pre-cdfill]

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

## 2nd

Fill sequence:

**Starting point:**

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>><kbd>H</kbd>><kbd>F</kbd>><kbd>I</kbd>><kbd>S</kbd> Then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>><kbd>down</kbd>><kbd>down</kbd>><kbd>down</kbd>><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

---

Personally I see the sequence fill as to cumbersome so below is a quick macro to do the same

```
Sub dragSeries()
    Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlAutoFill, Date:=xlDay, _
        Trend:=False
End Sub
```

Just assign it to say <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and enjoy