# auto-fill a formula referring to table columns without mouse (keyboard only)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working with formulas summarizing table columns (e.g. `SUM(Table1[Column1]`) and I would like to fill the formula to the right using only the keyboard.

When I autofill my range by mouse drag, it works fine (`[Column1]` => `[Column2]` is automatically updated), however I can't find a way to make it working with keyboard, it always manage my references as absolute ones.

I've tried all the answers to this question: [Excel Auto-Fill a Series Without Mouse (Keyboard Only)](https://superuser.com/questions/270018/excel-auto-fill-a-series-without-mouse-keyboard-only) (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>;  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> &  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), they work well formulas with standard cell references, but none of them works for me.

Of course my formulas are more complex then the example posted above, and also for other reasons it's not an option to change from table references to standard ones.

Is there any other trick I could try?

(I know it probably can be done in VBA and then adding the macro to Quick Access Toolbar, or create a shortcut to it, but now I'm not interested in it, as my toolbar is already too crowded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

(`->` indicates you don't hold the previous button. `+` means you do)

Firstly, select the first cell with your formula, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and tap <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to the last column you want the formula in.

Then:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> `->` <kbd>H</kbd> `->` <kbd>F</kbd> `->` <kbd>I</kbd> `->` <kbd>S</kbd> `->` <kbd>Alt</kbd> `+` <kbd>F</kbd> `->` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

[image]