# How to extend a a sequential pattern in Excel without using a mouse?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I would like to extend a sequential pattern in Excel as in the link below.

http://www.worldstart.com/ms-excel-extending-your-sequential-pattern/

However, is there a way to do that without using a mouse?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate. http://superuser.com/questions/270018/excel-auto-fill-a-series-without-mouse-keyboard-only

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] is there a way to do that without using a mouse?

Yes, there is.

#### Keyboard shortcut

In Excel 2013 select the range like this:

[image: Excel Fill Series Before]

And then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Explanation

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to activate the accelerator keys,
2. followed by <kbd>H</kbd> to select the `Home` ribbon,
3. followed by <kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd> to select the `Fill` button
4. followed by <kbd>S</kbd> to select the `Series` menu entry
5. followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command.

#### Result

The result looks like this:

[image: Excel Fill Series After]