# Excel: Using keyboard to replicate functionality of clicking bottom right corner of box to autofill

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When you click the bottom right corner of a selected cell, excel autofills down the column until the end of an **adjacent** column's data.

I primarily use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, but this will autofill until the end of that column's data, not the adjacent one.

How do I do what happens when you click the bottom right corner using only the keyboard?

Comment: You can do a simple Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V to copy the formula and paste in the next cell, and Excel will adjust it accordingly

Comment: I have updated my question to better clarify what I am looking for. My problem is going to the bottom of an adjacent column's data. Right now, I have to use the arrow keys to go into the adjacent column, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to go to the bottom of that column, use the arrow keys to move again to my column, put text in that cell to mark the bottom of the adjacent column's data in the column I want to autofill down. Then, I have to navigate back up and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> (or copy and paste) to fill down.

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

**manually (no mouse, only keyboard)**:

Write the item in the first cell
Use the Shift+down arrow key to select all the cells you want to fill.
Touch <kbd>F2</kbd> key to bring the cursor in the first cell.
Touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

or with this **macro**:

```
Sub mimic()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & N)
End Sub
```

will perform the fill-down:

[image]

To learn more about being **mouse-less** see:

[All Answers](https://superuser.com/questions/270018/excel-auto-fill-a-series-without-mouse-keyboard-only)

Comment: So instead of having to hold the down arrow when I do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, I want to be able to hit one key (or use one shortcut) to jump to B19 from B1, like how if you click the bottom right corner on B1 to autofill down the column, it will automatically stop at B19.

Comment: @user7758051  I can give you a one-key-touch macro if you are comfortable with macros.