# Why autofill with keyboard shortcut doesn't work in my Excel 2021?

Tags: microsoft-excel

According to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/270018/excel-auto-fill-a-series-without-mouse-keyboard-only), in order to do autofill with keyboard (without using double clicking on fill handle with mouse) one can select the cells and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd>  to autofill down and I can only do autofill right with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> .  I tried to use autofill manually from the Home tab but it didn't work too. In fact I can do autofill down only with double clicking on fill handle.

But unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. In Options> Advanced I checked that "Enable fill handle and cell-drag-and-drop" is checked. I'm wondering how to do autofill down with keyboard.

Comment: With these shortcuts it will fill down/right to the selected cells only, not all the way down to the last non-empty value in a row next to it, like it does with double clicking.

Comment: @P.b Oh thanks! Is there any shortcut to do the same function as double clicking?

Comment: What's wrong with double-clicking? Otherwise not that I 'm aware of. You may create a shortcut in VBA, but if it already exists (double clicking), why bother?

Comment: Did your keyboard have Fn key?

Comment: @Lee Yes it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to make a selection to use those shortcuts. This is easy enough with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the arrow keys. I use this way to:

a) Ensure that I'm filling down even if there are blanks in the column to the left

b) Ensure I'm only filling down the range I want to fill down (if you use the "Go To">"Special">"Last Cell" method, you might end up in the wrong place in complex worksheets)

It may seem long-winded, but I'm trying to offer as much detail as possible. It's actually quite quick when you get used to it.

E.g.

From your starting cell, if you want to fill-down to the last used cell in the column to the left, you can do this:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to take you to the bottom of the sheet in the current column
2. <kbd>←</kbd> to go to the column to the left
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to get to the last used cell in the column to the left of your fill-down column
4. <kbd>→</kbd> to get back to your fill-down column
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to select from the bottom of your fill-down column to the first value in the fill-down area.
6. Adjust the fill down selection by keeping <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed and tapping up or down.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

If you already know the address of the bottom of the column you want to fill-down, you can skip steps 1 through 4, just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for "Go to" and enter the address, press enter, then continue from step 5.